# Bug with selected rows in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

Sometimes when I select 1 row in my UITableView, an other row turns out to selected state too. Where could be the bug?

In **didSelectRowAtIndexPath**:

```
cartCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    cell.crossImage.hidden = NO;
}
else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.crossImage.hidden = YES;
}
```

in my **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellCart";
cartCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[cartCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

    Join *join = [_fetchByRecipe objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.ingredientName.text = join.ingredient.name;
    cell.ingredientCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", join.count];
    cell.ingredientUnit.text = join.ingredient.units;


if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
    cell.crossImage.hidden = YES;
}
else {
    cell.crossImage.hidden = NO;
}

return cell;
```

Comment: post your cellForRowAtIndexPath method code.

Comment: what happend when you select particuler cell?at that time only 2 cells are selected or when you scroll the tableview it'l happend?

Comment: YES! when I scroll tableView!!! the second selected cell is still not visible when a I prepare select

Comment: Are you SURE you're using didSelectRow and not didDeselectRow?

Comment: look at the answer in this one: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170260/ios-6-table-scrolling-causing-issues/15190034#15190034

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below

In **didSelectRowAtIndexPath**:

```
Join *join = [_fetchByRecipe objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];
join.isSelected = !join.isSelected;
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

in my **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellCart";
cartCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[cartCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

    Join *join = [_fetchByRecipe objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];
    cell.ingredientName.text = join.ingredient.name;
    cell.ingredientCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", join.count];
    cell.ingredientUnit.text = join.ingredient.units;

cell.accessoryType = join.isSelected?UITableViewCellAccessoryNone:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;


return cell;
```

**Edited 1**
Just add a `BOOL` property to you class `Join` as `isSelected`.. and use my edited answer, it should work..

**Edited 2**

```
[_fetchByRecipe objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

to

```
[_fetchByRecipe objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: something wrong... not in your code! When I scroll tableView the cells take checked or unchecked state themselves ))

Comment: _fetchByRecipe is a NSFetchedResultsController and it don't accept indexPath.row

Comment: @Romowski Did you try by adding a `BOOL` Property ? I think it should work, there is nothing wrong in it..

Comment: Join is a NSSubClass from Join entity. Should I add this property to Entity or only to subclass?

Comment: The Join entity already has property inCart (0 or 1). All the data that shows in this tableView is with inCart = 1 (these are need to buy ingredients).. May be I can use this property, because after select several rows I would like to "delete" them by changing inCart to 0?